# Gatsby develop V4 won’t switch between git branches

Tags: git, gatsby, git-branch, git-status

I have created a new git branch in my GatsbyJS project to work on a new feature, then running "gatsby clean" + "gatsby develop" to view the update, if I shut down the server and change back (checkout) to the master/main branch and run again "gatsby clean" + "gatsby develop" I can still see the updated version. Isn’t the browser supposed to show the original version without any changes?

I ran "gatsby clean" before "gatsby develop" everytime I switch branch and used two diferent browsers.

Another thing that I noticed (maybe this is ok), when I check "git status" I can see that the same file with the update is waiting to be commited on both branches.

As a side note I have basic gatsby-conf and gatsby-browser configuration

Comment: Maybe your browser cached the old version. Try doing a hard refresh (Ctrl+Shift+R). Also check the code to be sure it is really what you think it is.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you, yes I did that with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean your cache by running:

```
gatsby clean
```

This will delete your `/public` and your `.cache` folder. Keep in mind that the code you are seeing when building your site is under `/public` folder, so it makes sense to remove it to see the previous changes.

As a personal option, I normally tweak my develop command by adding a `gatsby clean` before, just to avoid this kind of issues in the `package.json`.

If you change something, and then you check out to another branch, the changes will come with you to the branch because they are not committed or staged. Git is aware that there's a file changed, but they're not attached to anything locally. If you want that changes to "don't come with you" when you check out you should commit/push them, or running a `git stash`, check out to the new branch and whenever you want you can recover them by running `git stash pop` (or discard them with `git checkout .`)

Comment: Voted up for the great advise, looks like is a git issue, I edited my question again.

Comment: I edited the answer. You aren't discarding the changed because you don't commit or stage the changes, so they are coming with you. If you want to remove the changes, run `git checkout .`. If you want to stand by the changes run `git stash` to drop it and `git stash pop` to recover them.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have local changes that you haven't committed when you run `git checkout` or `git switch`. This is what I am hinting at in my comment to check the code. When you see behavior that you don't expect, the first thing to do is to check the code to determine why that behavior happens.

To manage this, you have a few options:

1. Checkout the branch you were working on and commit your changes.
2. Use `git stash` to create a temporary commit. Then you can checkout main and run your code to see that version of your app. When you are ready to continue work, check out your other branch and run `git stash apply` to get your changes back.